# Accessing the object referenced in a logical condition

Tags: r

I am writing an xor function for a class, so although any recommendations on currently existing xor functions would be nice, I have to write my own. I have searched online, but have not been able to find any solution so far. I also realize my coding style may be sub-optimal. All criticisms will be welcomed.

I writing a function that will return an element-wise TRUE iff one condition is true. Conditions are given as strings, else they will throw an error due to unexpected symbols (e.g. >). I would like to output a list of the pairwise elements of a and b in which my xor function is true.

The problem is that, while I can create a logical vector of xor T/F based on the conditions, I cannot access the objects directly to subset them. It is the conditions that are function arguments, not the objects themselves.

```
'%xor%' <- function(condition_a, condition_b) {
  # Perform an element-wise "exclusive or" on the conditions being true.
  if (length(eval(parse(text= condition_a))) != length(eval(parse(text= condition_b))))
     stop("Objects are not of equal length.")  # Objects must be equal length to proceed
  logical_a <- eval(parse(text= condition_a))  # Evaluate and store each logical condition
  logical_b <- eval(parse(text= condition_b))
  xor_vector <- logical_a + logical_b == 1  # Only one condition may be true.
  xor_indices <- which(xor_vector == TRUE)  # Store a vector which gives the indices of the elements which satisfy the xor condition.
  # Somehow access the objects in the condition strings
  list(a = a[xor_indices], b = b[xor_indices])  # Desired output
}

# Example:
a <- 1:10
b <- 4:13
"a < 5" %xor% "b > 4"
```

Desired output:

```
$a
 [1]  1  5  6  7  8  9 10
$b
 [1]  4  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

I have thought about doing a combination of `ls()` and `grep()` to find existing object names in the conditions, but this would run into problems if the objects in the conditions were not initialized. For example, if someone tried to run `"c(1:10) < 5" %xor% "c(4:13) > 4"`.

Comment: For a start, you can skip the for-loop and generate `xor_vector <- logical_a+logical_b == 1`. I'm struggling a bit to understand your question, as your current function seems to return the desired output, due to R's scoping rules.

Comment: The complaint about 'unexpected symbol' is because of precedence and order of operations; override these with `(a < 5) %xor% (b > 4)`. You could then get the values with `a = eval(substitute(condition_a)[[2]][[2]])`, but would be thwarted if the user said `((a < 5)) %xor% (b > 4)`, or any number of other formulations;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the for-loop. I will edit to include that.

The problem with the function is that "a" and "b" may not (1) always be called a and b, and (2) may not always be initialized prior to calling the xor function, so the list(a = a[], b = b[]) may not always work. 

So I was trying to find a way to find the object acted-upon by a logical condition (i.e. pull the object referenced in "a < 5" or "c(1:10) < 5". Not sure if there is even a way of doing so, though.